# How do I check the event-history of a (possibly deleted) ec2-instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was running some scripts on an instance on the AWS free tier that I may I have deleted but I am not sure when I deleted the instance.

I have the public DNS of that instance and I'm unable to find it anywhere on my console.

Is there any way I can find out when I deleted the instance, if I indeed did?

Thanks

Comment: short answer: no, long answer: nope

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to use Amazon CloudTrail if you have access. There you can use filters to select EC2 instance history, for example, and see which account was responsible for its deletion, as well as other things like volume attachment, when it was spun up, etc! Sorry if that's two years too late.

Example of CloudTrail Dashboard:

[image: Example of CloudTrail Dashboard]